# MFMailComposeViewController Not Working- Swift

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to have it so when the user clicks a button an email is formed with a subject and a recipient. Below is a sample of my code:

```
func emailMe(sender:UIButton!){
    var emailSubject = "subject"
    var toRecipents = ["example@gmail.com"]
    var mcvc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mcvc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mcvc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mcvc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

    self.presentViewController(mcvc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When i click the button this appears [image]

Heading

Not only is the recipient not filled in, but the text fields do not allow you to type anything into them. Also this alert appears. [image]

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Xcode 6 and `MFMailComposeViewController` - you can test it properly on your device. Please file a radar: https://bugreport.apple.com/